# MySQL COUNT where and COUNT all

Tags: mysql

I have a table (sales) which has four columns;

```
id, user_id, product_id, and date_added.
```

I need to count the number of products with a certain id which have been sold by a user, and also get an overall count of products sold by that user in the current month.

I cant manage to sum the total products. I have;

```
SELECT user_id, product_id, count(user_id) 
FROM sales 
WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
GROUP BY user_id, product_id;
```

how do I sum the total sales for a user, so I can get a percentage of total sales which are a specific product_id?

I expect my output to look something like this;

```
|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|user_id   |product_id|sales     |total     |
|----------|----------|----------|----------|
|1         |4         |6         |82        |
|2         |4         |3         |121       |
|3         |4         |8         |93        |      
|----------|----------|----------|----------|
```

where total is the total number of sales made by the user.

(Is should mention that I don't need mysql to calculate the percentage - just to get the sum of all product sales)

thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the intended output because i dont feel the data you want as output fits into a single output table with `GROUP BY` used on `user_id, product_id`

Comment: Hi @harsh, thanks for asking, I have updated my question with the desired output table.

Comment: if there are multiple `product_id` for a single `user_id` then u want `total` to be repeated ? I dont think thats a good idea!

Comment: @harsh, im trying to plot a column graph (from the Google chart Tools), which shows the sales of all types of product per user (salesperson), and so I need a total of all their sales so I can display figures in each column as a percentage of the total sales for the salesperson. It might not be the way to do it, but it would work for me : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to use a subquery since you are relying on aggregate functions to do the counting

```
SELECT user_id, @pid:= product_id as product_id, count(user_id),
         (SELECT count(*)
          FROM sales
          WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH( now() )
               AND product_id = @pid
          group by user_id
         ) as total_product_sales
FROM sales 
WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH( now() ) 
GROUP BY user_id, product_id;
```

Comment: I would correct this answer, because as I understand, we have to calculate count of products, but not users:

Comment: `SELECT user_id, product_id, 
count(product_id) as prod_count, 
(
 SELECT count(product_id) 
 FROM sales 
 WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(now()) and user_id = t1.user_id 
 GROUP BY user_id
) as total_prods
FROM sales t1
WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(now()) 
GROUP BY user_id, product_id`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I didn't much understand what u want...

This query would give u the "subtotals" for a given user

```
 SELECT product_id, count(user_id) 
 FROM sales 
 WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
   AND user_id='YOUR_USER_ID'
 GROUP BY product_id with rollup;
```

*OR* if you want the overall percentage given a product id and a user id for the current month:

```
 SELECT 
        PARTIAL_SALES/TOTAL_SALES*100 
 FROM
      (SELECT USER_ID,
              count(user_id) AS PARTIAL_SALES
         FROM sales 
              WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
              AND user_id='YOUR_USER_ID'
              AND PRODUCT_ID='YOUR_PRODUCT_ID'
          GROUP BY USER_ID) AS PARTIAL,
      (SELECT USER_ID, 
              count(user_id) as TOTAL_SALES
         FROM sales 
              WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
          GROUP BY USER_id) AS TOTAL1
 WHERE PARTIAL.USER_ID=TOTAL.USER_ID;
```

Comment: HI Davide, and thanks for your answer. I dont need the percentage to be calculated within the sql call, I can do this afterwards with the raw figures.

Comment: Then just use the first query, the rollup one. It shall give u the subtotals for every product id AND last line will be the overall total one

Comment: I want to build a column chart with the results, showing the sales of each type of product for each sales person. I cant add the user_id or product_id in manually, they have to be part of the query

Comment: SELECT user_id,
       product_id, 
       count(user_id) 
 
  FROM sales 

 WHERE MONTH(date_added) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 

 GROUP BY user_id, product_id with rollup; 
      


should do the work.. u'll have results like  
user1 prod1 10
user1 prod2 20
user1 NULL  30    <-- subtotal for user1
user2 prod1 100
user2 prod3 2
user2 NULL  102   <-- subtotal for user2
NULL  NULL  132   <-- subtotal of all users